# What is the millionth decimal digit of the $ 10^{10^{10^{10}}} $-th prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

> What is the millionth decimal digit of the $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$th prime?

(This prime, with more than $10^{10^{10}}$ decimal digits, is far larger than [the largest "known" prime](http://primes.utm.edu/largest.html#biggest).) The answer should include a proof of correctness. I'm posting this question in the spirit of [this advice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), and will eventually post an answer (with proof of a more general result) if no one else does so.

**NB**: The notation $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$ means the same as $10^{(10^{(10^{10})})}$, and the "millionth digit" means the millionth digit from the left, as usually written (i.e., the most significant digit is leftmost and is called the 1st digit).

**Afterthought**: It might have been more impressive to have asked for the $10^{10}$th digit of, say, the $10^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}$th prime (that digit being $8$), since perhaps no one has ever before computed the ten-billionth digit of a particular prime.

Comment: Does $(10^{1000})$th prime number has million digits ?

Comment: @pedja: I've added a note showing the intended $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$.

Comment: I hope this has nothing to do with Benford's Law.

Comment: The millionth most significant digit, or millionth least significant digit?

Comment: @pedja: In case you're not familiar with the conventions ... Both 10^10^10^10 and $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$ are intended to mean 10^(10^(10^10)), which is a number with 1 + 10^(10^10) digits. By [Rosser's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_theorem), the $n$th prime is greater than $n \ ln \ n$, so the 10^(10^(10^10))th prime has far more than 10^(10^10) digits.

Comment: Known upper and lower bounds for $p_n$ are in principle sharp enough to pin down the millionth digit. However, finding $\log n$ to sufficient accuracy may be difficult.

Comment: @percusse: This has nothing to do with Benford's law.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Indeed, that's the basis of my proof. There's no problem computing the relevant logarithm to the required number of significant digits.

Comment: @user7530: I've added a note that should make this clear. The intended digit is the millionth most-significant digit (i.e., counting from the left, as usually written, the leftmost digit being considered the 1st digit).

Comment: @r.e.s.: Looking forward to learning about the computation method for the logarithm when you post the solution.

Comment: @leslietownes: How do you know that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following bound on the $n$-th prime ($p_n$) is known: for $n > 6$,
$$
n\left(\log{n} + \log\log{n} - 1\right) < p_n < n\left(\log{n} + \log\log{n}\right).
$$
For $n=10^{10^{10^{10}}}$, we have $$\log{n} = 10^{10^{10}}\log{10},$$ a number with ten billion and one digits before the decimal point, and $$\log\log{n} = 10^{10}\log{10} + \log\log{10} \approx 23 025 850 931,$$ a number with eleven digits before the decimal point.  Since the latter number is about ten billion digits shorter than the former, the millionth digit of $p_n$ is the same as the millionth digit of $n\log{n}$; that is, we can ignore the $n\log\log{n}$ correction$^{\dagger}$.  But
$$
n\log{n} = 10^{10^{10^{10}}}\cdot 10^{10^{10}}\log{10} = 10^{\left(10^{10^{10}} + 10^{10}\right)}\log{10}
$$
is a large power of ten multiplied by $\log{10}$, and so its millionth digit is the same as the millionth digit of $\log{10}$ (i.e., the 999999-th digit after the decimal).  This digit can be found in a number of places (e.g., at [[numberworld.org]](http://www.numberworld.org/digits/Log%2810%29/)), and is equal to $5$.

---

$^\dagger$ This relies on our knowing that the digits *after* the millionth digit of $n\log{n}$ are not an enormous string of $9$'s.  In fact, the next digit is $0$ (since that is the millionth digit of $\log{10}$ after the decimal), justifying this step.

Answer (score 13):

A similar approach as in the accepted answer, but using a tighter bound from [Dusart](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-01037-6/S0025-5718-99-01037-6.pdf)  ...

**Theorem**: If $m$ is a positive integer, then the first $k-1$ digits of the $10^{10^m}$th prime are just those of $\log 10$, where $k$ is the greatest integer such that $(k \le \lfloor m - \log_{10} m \rfloor \wedge d_k \lt 9)$, and $d_k$ is the $k$th digit of $\log  10$.

**Proof**: [Rosser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_theorem) proved that $p_n \gt n \log n$, and [Dusart](http://www.unilim.fr/laco/theses/1998/T1998_01.pdf) proved that $p_n \le (n \log n)(1 + r_n)$ for all $n \ge 39017$, where $r_n = \frac{\log \log n - 0.9484}{\log n} \gt 0$. Therefore,

$p_n = n \log n  + (n \log n) \ \epsilon_n $ for all $n \ge 39017$, where $0 \lt \epsilon_n \le r_n$.

Now suppose $n = 10^{10^m}$, where $m$ is a positive integer ($m \ge 1$ ensures $n \ge 39017$, so Dusart's bound applies). Then

$n \log n = 10^{10^m + m} \log 10$

which, in base $10$, is just $\log 10$ with the decimal point shifted $10^m + m$ places to the **right**.

Now $\log \log 10 < 0.9484$, so

$r_n = 10^{-m} \ (m + \frac{\log \log 10 - 0.9484}{\log 10}) < 10^{-m} m \le 10^{-\lfloor m - \log_{10} m \rfloor}$,

and hence

$(n \log n) \ \epsilon_n <  (n \log n) \ 10^{-\lfloor m - \log_{10} m \rfloor}$

where the right-hand side is seen to be, in base $10$, just $n \log n$ with the decimal point shifted $\lfloor m - \log_{10} m \rfloor$ places to the **left**.

Thus, if $k$ is the greatest integer satisfying both (1) $k \le \lfloor m - \log_{10} m \rfloor$, and (2) the $k$th digit is less than 9 (ensuring that no carry from the right can affect the $(k-1)$th digit), then adding $(n \log n) \ \epsilon_n$ to $n \log n$ does not affect the first $k-1$ digits of the latter term. **QED**

NB: This result generalizes to the $b^{b^{m}}$th prime, for any integer base $b$ such that $2 \le b \le 13$, and for integer $m \ge \log_b \log_b 39017$.  The restrictions are to ensure that Dusart's bound can be applied.

**Example**: For any $m \ge 10^6 + 8$ (e.g., $m = 10^{10}$, as in the posted question), the first million digits of the $10^{10^m}$th prime are just those of $\log 10$. This is because for $m = 10^6 + 8$, $\lfloor m - \log_{10} m \rfloor = 10^6 + 1$, giving $k$ as the greatest integer such that $(k \le 10^6 + 1 \wedge d_k \lt 9)$. Direct computation (e.g., using [Sage](http://sagemath.org/), which took less than a minute) shows that $k-1 = 10^6$, $d_{k-1} = 5$, $d_k = 0 \ (\lt 9)$.