# Any Mersenne prime contains two consecutive 9 digits?

Tags: number-theory

The kids with me were each asked to pick a number. It crossed my mind that a smart aleck might answer with a description of some number that we have never actually computed. I remembered that a limited number of Mersenne primes have been computed, so I suppose answering "the nth Mersenne prime" would work, for some n greater than 49.

Alternatively, how about a Mersenne prime whose decimal digits include two consecutive 9's? Is there one for which the decimal representation has been computed?

If there is not, do we know whether one exists?

If there is one, is there some other small sequence of digits that certainly occurs in a Mersenne prime, and yet we do not know any such Mersenne prime in particular?

Comment: Barring computer error, $M_{13}=2^{521}-1$ has a double $9$.  But...what was the question?

Comment: If your goal is just to "specify" a number which may or may not exist, why not go with "the smallest Fermat prime greater than $65537$" or something like that?

Comment: Most numbers of over $100$ digits have a double $9$, so it is likely that all the ones greater than $M_{13}$ have double $9$s as well.

Comment: All digits of all known Mersenne primes can be computed in a matter of seconds.  There is absolutely no unexplored territory in which there can be a digit string that we know *must* appear but we haven't found it yet.  Either it's contained in one of the known Mersenne primes (thus we found it), or it isn't (thus we can't know it must appear).  We haven't proved there are infinitely many Mersenne primes — we don't have a proof that the current list is missing anything (although it probably is).

Comment: Oh well, doesn't seem to lead to something interesting. Thanks for the comments and answers. I suppose a better smart-aleck number is (and I see this is on the site already http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848854) "the googol-th prime." It exists, it's unique, it has a succinct definition as the prime p for which $\pi$(p) = 10^100, and I can feel certain that no one knows its decimal digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2^{521}-1$ i.e. 
     $6864797660130609714981900799081393217269435300143305409394463459185543183397656052122559640661454554977296311391480858037121987999716643812574028291115057151$ 
has two consecutive $9$s ..............            ^^

Many larger Mersenne primes have more examples